# How to use Google Earth on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mobile

I am just wondering that is there any way to integrate the Earth browsers in an iPhone app (native or web).
Is there any way or any suggestion friend, this is an open discussion so please let ideas flow in.

Thank you All,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible. Read [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=5b7057d421e5f664&hl=en).

Comment: This link is dead: https://support.google.com/?gpf=d/category-topic/mobile/apple-devices/LzaP41Qd-Jg