# google earth api for iphone

Tags: iphone, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I need  google earth api  for my iPhone application can somebody just provide idea or link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google Earth on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276480/how-to-use-google-earth-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no public API for the Google Earth iphone/ipad application. http://www.google.com/mobile/earth/

You can however load custom kml into the application on both devices allowing for overlays, models, tours, etc by using 'My Maps' in a maps.google.com account.

To get your KML into IOS Google Earth

1. Go to Google Maps http://maps.google.com/
2. Choose "My Maps"
3. Choose "make a new map"
4. Click on "import".
5. Choose the kml/kmz file you wish to add.
6. On the iphone/ipad Google Earth Application choose "Layers"
7. Choose "My Maps".
8. Choose the map you created in step 2

Your imported kml/kmz data will now show in the IOS application just like in the full Google Earth Client.

Comment: Thanks Fraser! But unfortunately that's not my idea. I would like to build a map like google maps, but with terrain like google earth.. on an app, not using Google Earth app. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Frade Huh? That doesn't make any sense at all - there is no terrain in google maps.

Comment: I know, that's why I was asking for a solution using google earth, but it seems that there is any API.